# using the datatables jquery plugin with asp.net mvc2

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, datatables

I started to use the jquery datatables plugin for asp.net mvc2. I have the following code in the index.aspx page of the view.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#employeeviews').dataTable({
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "/Employee/listEmployees",
            "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                alert("aodata is : "+aoData);
                alert("as source is : "+sSource);
                $.ajax({
                    "dataType": 'json',
                    "type": "POST",
                    "url": sSource,
                    "data": aoData,
                    "success": fnCallback
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Now that I have written all these, in the controller, i have an action that returns the partialview.

```
  [HttpPost]
    //public ActionResult listEmployees()
    public JsonResult listEmployees()
    {
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            Models.EmployeeModel empModel = new Models.EmployeeModel();
            //return Json(PartialView("EmployeeList", empModel.getAllEmployees()), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            //return Json(empModel.getAllEmployees());

            return Json(new
            {
                iTotalRecords = 11,
                iTotalDisplayRecords = 3,
                aaData = empModel.getAllEmployees()
            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
```

Now what i get is warning messagebox from jquery. I also tried to use the partial view method to return the partial view.

But I have a problem in this, where exactly can i get the output of the ajax response in the js file so that i can set the output accordingly in the view page, as it is not clear in this process. Also i am planning to handle the ajax and paging requests. When i am done with this, i can move to the other parts.

I am also going to test this with the use of the MVCContrib grid control so that the functionality is clear for me.

Comment: What is your question? What was the contents of this warning message box?

Comment: This is the error message `DataTables warning (tableid="employeeviews"): Added data (size undefined) does not match known number of columns(5)`

Comment: I want to use the ajax with the datatable in the asp.net mvc for handling the display of the data in the form of tables with paging, sorting etc

Comment: atlast i solved the sorting issues, but still struggling with the paging issues. i get the page no as 1 and not as 1,2. i.e. i have 15 records and have displayed 10 records. in the pagination, i have 1 only actually i should have 2. If i get this, all my datatables problems are going to end.. any suggestions on this point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted out by myself and no need for another answer.